# Possible issue with proposed solution to finding the Taylor Polynomial of $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ (a problem in Spivak's Calculus Chapter 20)

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

I wanted to confirm whether or not I am correctly identifying a mistake in the author-provided solution to the following problem (located within Spivak's *Calculus* 4th Ed.):

> Let $f$ be defined by: $\begin{cases} \frac{e^x-1}{x}\quad &x \neq 0\\ 1\quad & x=0\end{cases}\quad$ Find the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ for $f$ at $0$ and compute $f^{(k)}(0)$.

The solution manual reads as follows:

---

From $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)$, we get $f(x)=1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}+R_{n,0,f}(x)$, so $\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=\frac{1}{(k+1)!} \implies f^{(k)}(0)=\frac{1}{k+1}$.

---

My issue with this proof is that I think there is an omitted theorem from earlier in the chapter that is being erroneously (or perhaps 'prematurely') applied. The theorem I refer to reads as follows:

> Let $f$ be $n$-times differentiable at $a$, and suppose that $P$ is a polynomial in $(x-a)$ of degree $\leq n$, which equals $f$ up to order $n$ at $a$. Then $P=P_{n,a,f}$ (i.e. $P$ is the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ centered at $a$ of function $f$).

In Spivak's proposed solution, I believe that the following step is implicitly performed:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{e^x-1}{x}-\left(1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}\right)}{x^n}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}}{x^n}=0$$

I agree with the right portion of this limit, so it is likely true, but based on how the aforementioned theorem is written, we **cannot** therefore conclude that $1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}=P_{n,0,f}(x)$ because we have not shown that $f$ is $n$-times differentiable at $x=0$. In order for Spivak's proof to be valid, I first need to show that $f^{(n)}(0)$ *exists*, correct?

Comment: Do you agree that $1+xf(x) = e^x$?

Comment: My point is actually that, if you grant that, then the only questionable step I see is where the solution manual writes $f(x) = [\ldots] + R_{n,0,f}(x)$ instead of $f(x) = [\ldots] + \frac{R_{n,0,\exp}(x)}{x}$.  We don't need to care about the Taylor polynomials because, with the $R$s, we have the entire function.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry, I am a little confused. The structure of this question is to *find* the Taylor polynomial of $f$. Are you saying that $[\cdots]$ is *not* the Taylor polynomial of $f$? If that is what you are saying, then I would agree with you...but the purpose of this question is to find the Taylor polynomial of $f$, so I would think that this is not the appropriate interpretation? (Thank you for your input).

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "we don't need to care about the Taylor polynomials _while finding the derivatives_ because with the $R$s, we have the entire function."  The structure of the solution is this: "Use the Taylor polynomial of $e^x$ of degree $n+1$ along with the remainder function to find a polynomial $P(x)$ and a function $R(x)$ whose limiting behavior at $0$ _looks_ like a remainder function and $f(x) = P(x) + R(x)$.  From the limiting behavior of $R(x)$, find the derivatives of $f$ at $0$.  _Then_ conclude $P(x)$ is a Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$."

Comment: @BrianMoehring I posted an answer that I think is capturing your comments. Maybe? A lot of the work was never discussed in Spivak up to this point, so I derived most of the results myself and provided them in the answer. Based off of your brief comments, I didn't expect it to be as much work as it was, which makes me think that maybe I misunderstood your point. Regardless, thank you for the input; it allowed me to arrive at a satisfying explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I am uncertain if I am interpreting *Brian Moehring*'s comments correctly, but here is how I think we can get around any logic-violations. It is certainly true that:

$f(x)=1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}+\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}$

Also, using Spivak's formulation, which (in the general case) implicitly invokes the Axiom of Choice, the remainder function $\displaystyle R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)$ can be conceptualized as: $\displaystyle \frac{e^{\phi(x)}}{(n+2)!}x^{n+2}$, where $\phi(x)=t$ and satisfies $0 \lt |\phi(x)| \lt x$. As such, we note that for any $\displaystyle m \in \{1,2,\cdots,n+1\}: \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\phi(x)}}{(n+2)!}\frac{x^{n+2}}{x^m}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\phi(x)}}{(n+2)!}\times \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{n+2}}{x^m}=\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\times 0=0.$

It is important to see that at this point in the proof, **we do not know** if $1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$ is the $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ and if, therefore, $\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}$ is the corresponding remainder term $R_{n,0,f}(x)$. However, we *do know* that $R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)$ is a differentiable function. **Why**?

Well, $R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)$ is derived from the expression:

$\exp(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x) \quad (*)$

$\exp$ is an infinitely differentiable function for $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ and $1+\frac{x}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, a polynomial, is an infinitely differentiable function $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. As such, rearranging $(*)$ to: $R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\exp(x)$ shows that, indeed, $R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)$ is differentiable $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. In particular, we have that:

\begin{align}R^{(k)}_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n+1-k}\frac{\frac{(k+i)!}{i!}}{(k+i)!}x^i\right)(-1)+\exp(x) \\&=\exp(x)-\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n+1-k}\frac{x^i}{i!}\right)\end{align}

And observe: $$\lim_{x \to 0}R^{(k)}_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)=1-1=0$$

which tells us the $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{R^{(k)}_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x^j}=0$ for $j+k \leq n+1$ (just apply L-hopital's rule $j$ times) $\quad (\dagger)$.

Accordingly, we can make the following argument (which is simply applying the standard definition of the derivative):

\begin{align}f^{(1)}(0)&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f^{(0)}(x)-f^{(0)}(0)}{x} \\&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}+\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}-1}{x} \\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}}{x}+\frac{\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}}{x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}}{x}+\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x^2}}\\&=\frac{1}{2}+0=\frac{1}{2}\end{align}

\begin{align}f^{(2)}(0)&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f^{(1)}(x)-f^{(1)}(0)}{x} \\&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2x}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}+\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(1)}(x)}{x}-\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}}{x} \\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2x}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}}{x}+\frac{\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(1)}(x)}{x}}{x}+\frac{-\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x^2}}{x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2x}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n+1)!}}{x}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(1)}(x)}{x^2}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x^3}\\&=\frac{1}{3}+0 +0=\frac{1}{3}\end{align}

We can now take a good guess as to what $f^{(k)}(0)$ is: $\frac{1}{k+1}$. To explicitly prove this, though, we first need to derive a general expression (provable with induction...not shown) for the $k$-th derivative of $\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}$:

$$\left[\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}}{I}\right]^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i \frac{k!}{(k-i)!}R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(k-i)}(x)}{x^{i+1}}$$

as well as a general formula (provable with induction...not shown) for the $k$-th derivative of the polynomial portion $P_f$ of $f$:

$$P_f^{(k)}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(k+i)!}{i!(k+1+i)!}x^i$$

Therefore, let us now make the inductive proof of the following claim (where $k+1 \leq n$):

\begin{align} f^{(k+1)}(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)+f^{(k)}(0)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{P_f^{(k)}(x)+\left[\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}}{I}\right]^{(k)}(x)-\frac{1}{k+1}}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(k+i)!}{i!(k+1+i)!}x^i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i \frac{k!}{(k-i)!}R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(k-i)}(x)}{x^{i+1}}\right)-\frac{1}{k+1}}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac{(k+i)!}{i!(k+1+i)!}x^i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i \frac{k!}{(k-i)!}R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(k-i)}(x)}{x^{i+1}}\right)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}\frac{(k+i)!}{i!(k+1+i)!}x^i}{x}+\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{(-1)^i \frac{k!}{(k-i)!}\color{red}{R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(k-i)}(x)}}{\color{red}{x^{i+2}}}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+2)!}+0\\
&=\frac{1}{k+2}\end{align}

Quickly, I just wanted to emphasize that the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ colored symbols satisfy $(\dagger)$ because, given that $k+1 \leq n \implies k \leq n-1$...we have that $(k-i)+i+2=k+2 \leq n+1$, we must have that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}^{(k-i)}(x)}{x^{i+2}}=0$.

Given that for $k \in [0,n] \subset \mathbb Z: f^{(k)}(0)=\frac{1}{k+1}$, we can at long last make the following assertion:

\begin{align}f(x) &=1+\frac{x}{2!}+\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^3}{4!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}+\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}\\
&=\frac{1}{0+1}\frac{1}{0!}x^0+\frac{1}{1+1}\frac{1}{1!}x^1+\frac{1}{2+1}\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3+1}\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{n!}x^n+\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x} \\
&=\frac{f^{0}(x)}{0!}x^0+\frac{f^{1}(x)}{1!}x^1+\frac{f^{2}(x)}{2!}x^2+\frac{f^{3}(x)}{3!}x^3+\cdots+\frac{f^{n}(x)}{n!}x^n+\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}\end{align}

Of course, the polynomial portion is *precisely* the definition of an $n$-th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ centered at $a=0$...which necessarily means that $\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}$ is *precisely* the remainder term of said Taylor polynomial...i.e. $\frac{R_{n+1,0,\exp}(x)}{x}=R_{n,0,f}(x)$